# require module with promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, co

I wrap my each router module like below `IndexBase.js`,
if I want to require a module like `othercrudmodule.js`,
and these function have to execute with promise too,

I tried use `co` in the `othercrudmodule.js` too but I know absolutely not work

How to require them, structure this correctly?

IndexBase.js

```
  var co = require('co');
  var othercrudmodule = require('../../CustomModules/othercrudmodule');

  router.get('/q', function(req, res, next) {
    domain.run(function() {
      var dbClient = req.app.get('dbClient');
      // some promise crud database function ..
      // ..

      co(function *() {
        // yield promise crud database function


        // **should I use yield here too? or ?   
        // How to get sync result here with selectAll**
        var othercrudmoduleResult = yield othercrudmodule(dbClient).selectAll();

        // render result
      }).catch(onerror);
      function onerror(error) { 
        console.error(error.stack);
        res.send(error.stack);
      }
    });
    domain.on('error', function(error) { 
      console.error(error.stack); 
      res.send();
    });
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

othercrudmodule.js

```
var co = require('co');

var othercrudmodule = function(dbClient) {
  // some promise crud database function ..
  var selectArticle = function() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
      var domainB = require('domain').create();
      domainB.on('error', function(error) { domain.emit('error', error); });
      domainB.run(function() {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Tag0" ORDER BY "Name"';
        dbClient.Article.query(query,[], function(error, result) {
          var o = {};
          if (error != null) {
            o.error = error;
            fulfill(o);
          } else {
            o.result = result;
            fulfill(o);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  };

  // ... more promise crud database function ..


  var selectAll = function() {
    // **should I use co and yield in this module ??  I want selectAll return sync result**

    // co(function *() {
      // .... yield promise crud database function ??

      var o = [];
      var selectArticleResult = selectArticle();
      // console.log(selectArticle1Tag0Result);
      o.push(selectArticleResult.result.rows);


      return o;
    // }).catch(onerror);
    // function onerror(error) { 
    //   console.error(error.stack);
    //   res.send(error.stack);
    // }
  };

  var o = {};
  o.selectAll = selectAll;
  return o;
};


module.exports = othercrudmodule;
```

**Update**
the `selectAll` function not promise, so I get async result? then how to resolve it?
right now I use `yield othercrudmodule(dbClient).selectArticle()` get the correct sync result, but thats not what I want...

I want use `othercrudmodule(dbClient).selectAll()` , the function in the module execute some crud with database function then return a sync result.

Comment: Does something not work with the code you have posted? What do you mean by "*I want to put duplicate function in other module*"?

Comment: the function in `othercrudmodule`  will be async.  the duplicate function is those function I remove in `othercrudmodule` , because I will use in multiple router .

Comment: I don't see how the asynchrony of the function matters for its module placement or usage rate.

Comment: So you're concerned that `selectArticle` is the same function as `selectArticle1`? Why not just scrap one of them and simply call the other twice? What is the problem you have?

Comment: no, they are different function just for example.  my question is I just try to find a way in module how to use promise too

Comment: They are different? Looks quite the same to me. Still, I don't see your problem and what it has to do with modules. What does not work? Do you get an error? Please ask a *question*.

Comment: thanks for reply ,  but thats not the point about my question.

Comment: OK, so what is the point of your question then?

Comment: require a module the function inside contain promise function

Comment: That does seem to work, doesn't it? Are you getting any errors? It should not be different from requiring modules that contain non-promise functions.

Comment: I quote question in my code ,  if I use `yield` in router the function been execute in `othercrudmodule ` module,  not work to be sync.  will still be async

Comment: Well yes if the function returns a promise you're supposed to use `yield`. This has *nothing* to do with whether the function is from another module or not.

Comment: but I user `yield othercrudmodule(dbClient).selectAll();` the selectAll function not promise, so I get async result?  then how to resolve it?    right now I use `yield othercrudmodule(dbClient). selectArticle()` get the correct sync result, but thats not what I want

Comment: I don't think that's a good practice to mix promise and non-promise functions in your module selectArticle/selectAll doing same thing so they should act similarly, if one is promise-returning, other should be as well

Comment: `selectAll` should never sometimes return a promise and sometimes not. You should know whether it does or whether it doesn't. Regardless, even if it does not, `yield` will also work with plain values; `co` does not differ between them (a plain value is just "awaited" immediately).

Comment: @user1575921: "*but that's not what I want*" - Why not? What's wrong with it? What do you want instead?

Comment: I want  use yield othercrudmodule.(dbClient).selectAll() will return sync result, my problem is I know right now the selectAll function is wrong will only return a async result , my question is how to fix it

Comment: why not just convert your selectAll into promise as well?

Comment: @llamerr  would you show me some example code

Comment: you already have example in your selectArticle function. something like https://jsfiddle.net/eyo1ups6/ . i only tried koa/co once and in my module i just exported few generators which i can use with co or others

Comment: here is my code. not sure if it's good or not, http://plnkr.co/edit/rWXE4sHp6ddF9pnFZqF4?p=catalogue

Comment: @llamerr thanks !! please my update https://jsfiddle.net/eyo1ups6/1/  , there is callback in selectArticle function  (crud database function)  how to return the result  to selectAll

Comment: you don't need to change your getArticle code. it should return promise which is resolved with o. in my `pseudocode`(i don't think it's working) i used that o resolution as selectArticleResult which is "identical" (don't think it is...) to `var selectArticleResult = yield selectArticle();`

Comment: i think you need to read more docs on promises and generators to get better understanding of what is going on. here are some of my links http://justpaste.it/p3qx

Comment: @user1575921: "*I want use yield othercrudmodule.(dbClient).selectAll() will return sync result*" - that's not possible. If you're doing something asynchronous, you cannot return a sync results, that's like trying to look into the future. All that `co` (sic!) does is to simplify your *asynchronous code* so that you can write `yield` instead of using `.then()` callbacks on the promises.

Comment: Thanks so much for description and resource. I will try restructure my code